# How to fix Git error: key does not contain a section: trustexitcode

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-config

I was doing some work inside the git GUI SourceTree, and all of a sudden it crashed. When I opened it back up, all my repos were removed from SourceTree - no big deal. However, I noticed that now when I open up a git repo in my command line, I now see the following error:

`error: key does not contain a section: trustexitcode`

How could SourceTree crashing cause this error? Is it a problem with a config somewhere?

Comment: It's a similar issue to the linked possible-duplicate, but it happens because something wrote a *bad* configuration file. This means all the *good* settings are missing! You'll want to restore the `.git/config` file from a good backup if you can find one.

Comment: Thanks @torek Does that refer to a global git config file? Or a per-project git config file?

Comment: I think I see the issue. In my global .gitconfig, trustExitCode = true is not in a section...exactly what the error says lol. I'll see if removing it works.

Comment: Ah, OK, perhaps you haven't lost all the other settings. Would be a good idea to check though.

Comment: Yup, it's working now once I removed trustExitCode.